# How to show only first image in php

Tags: php, css

I want hide the exept first image,no need to use while write select query put LIMIT 0,1 for my situation i want select all images while showing that time i want show one images how to do this

Actually i am using photoswipe ref link http://photoswipe.com/ ,for this plugin showing the all images then we click means it show the image in big size for one by one,for me dont want like this,i want show first one image then we click the image it will come big size for one by one,

```
<div class="my-gallery" itemscope itemtype="">
<?php 
include('dbconfig.php');
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT ssmid, image  FROM user_timeline_photos");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
?>
<figure>
  <a href="img/cropped-images/<?php echo $row['image'];?>" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1600x1600">
      <img src="img/cropped-images/<?php echo $row['image'];?>" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" style='dispaly:none'/>
     //here i want to show that one image
  </a>
   <figcaption itemprop="caption description"><?php //echo'Upload Date'. $row['date_uploaded']?></figcaption>
</figure>
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: try this... `$row['image'][0]`.. it will get you the first value in the array...

Comment: @RajaR You want to show only the first image and not the other images, correct?

Comment: Yes i want to show only 1 st image

Answer (score 1):

Easiest would be to use index e.g. `$i`

```
<div class="my-gallery" itemscope itemtype="">
<?php 

include('dbconfig.php');
$i = 0;
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT ssmid, image  FROM user_timeline_photos WHERE ssmid='$ssmid'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
?>

 <figure <?php if(0 != $i) { ?>style="display:none;" <?php } ?>>
   <a href="img/cropped-images/<?php echo $row['image'];?>" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1600x1600">
      <img src="img/cropped-images/<?php echo $row['image'];?>" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" style='dispaly:none'/>
     //here i want to show that one image
   </a>
   <figcaption itemprop="caption description">
       <?php //echo'Upload Date'. $row['date_uploaded']?>
   </figcaption>
 </figure>

<?php $i++; } ?>
```

Comment: @RajaR Glad I could Help.

Comment: Nice solution. @RajaR if you don't want to show images except first image then why are you looping through all the images. After displaying the first image you can simply break out of the loop using `break` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css3 first:child elements to hide the first image for example

```
  .images_container:first-child { 
        display:none;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the counter.Try this

```
 <div class="my-gallery" itemscope itemtype="">
    <?php 
    include('dbconfig.php');
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT ssmid, image  FROM user_timeline_photos WHERE ssmid='$ssmid'");
    $count=0;
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    ?>
    <figure <?php ($counter==0)?'style="display:none;"':NULL ?>>
      <a href="img/cropped-images/<?php echo $row['image'];?>" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1600x1600">
          <img src="img/cropped-images/<?php echo $row['image'];?>" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
         //here i want to show that one image
      </a>
       <figcaption itemprop="caption description"><?php //echo'Upload Date'. $row['date_uploaded']?></figcaption>
    </figure>
     <?php $count++; } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative solution:**

Even though @pinkalvansia has given you an elegant solution, here's my alternative solution.

You can simply use a boolean variable(like `$boolean`) to check if it's the first image or not, and after displaying the first image you'll simply break out of the loop because if you want to show only the first image then there's no point looping through all the images.

```
<div class="my-gallery" itemscope itemtype="">
<?php 
    include('dbconfig.php');
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT ssmid, image  FROM user_timeline_photos WHERE ssmid='$ssmid'");

    $boolean = true;

    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
        if($boolean){
            // show image here
            ?>
            <figure>
                <a href="img/cropped-images/<?php echo $row['image'];?>" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1600x1600">
                <img src="img/cropped-images/<?php echo $row['image'];?>" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" style='dispaly:none'/>
                </a>
                <figcaption itemprop="caption description"><?php //echo'Upload Date'. $row['date_uploaded']?></figcaption>
            </figure>
            <?php
            break;
        }
    } 
?>
```

**Or even better:**

Rather than fetching all records, fetch only one record.

```
<div class="my-gallery" itemscope itemtype="">
<?php 
    include('dbconfig.php');
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT ssmid, image  FROM user_timeline_photos WHERE ssmid='$ssmid'");
    $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql); // fetches only one record
?>
<figure>
    <a href="img/cropped-images/<?php echo $row['image'];?>" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1600x1600">
    <img src="img/cropped-images/<?php echo $row['image'];?>" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" style='dispaly:none'/>
    </a>
    <figcaption itemprop="caption description"><?php //echo'Upload Date'. $row['date_uploaded']?></figcaption>
</figure>
```